# ResponseFormat.Json not responding JSON on production environment

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax, web-services, production-environment

On my localhost i have IIS 7.5 running on windows 7. On my production environment i have iis 7 running on Server Ent. 2008.

When i publish my code to production and run my jQuery ajax call i get an XML response, and i expect a JSON response.

I used fiddler to compare both request headers and they are identical.

**EDIT:** My service has the [ScriptService]:

```
[ScriptService]
public class Satellites : System.Web.Services.WebService {
```

webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public List<Satellite> GetSatellites()
{
    List<Satellite> satellites;

    if (!CacheHelper.Get(strSatelliteKey, out satellites))
    {
        //satellites not found so retrieve and add to cache for next lookup.
        satellites = GetLatestSatellites();
        CacheHelper.Add(satellites, strSatelliteKey);

    }

    return satellites;
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Satellites.asmx/GetSatellites",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var satellites = response.d;
        //            console.log(satellites);
        $.each(satellites, function (index, satellite) {
            Satellites.Items.push(new Satellites.Satellite(satellite.id, satellite.name, satellite.tle0, satellite.tle1, satellite.tle2));
            UI.ControlPanel.Satellites.create_li(satellite, index);
        });
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        var message = new UI.ControlPanel.Message("<p>There was an error retrieving source satellite information.</p>", UI.ControlPanel.Message.Type.ERROR);
    }
});
```

Response from Localhost:

```
{"d":[{,"id":10967,"name":"SEASAT1","tle0":null,"tle1":null,"tle2":null},{,"id":16613,"name":"SPOT1","tle0":null,"tle1":null,"tle2":null},{,"id":20436,"name":"SPOT2","tle0":"SPOT 2","tle1":"1 20436U 90005A   10320.17586019  .00000436  00000-0  83185-4 0  7240","tle2":"2 20436  98.6342  56.4544 0155718 145.6368 215.5023 14.62070104 81087"},{,"id":21574,"name":"ERS1","tle0":null,"tle1":null,"tle2":null},{,"id":21867,"name":"JERS1","tle0":null,"tle1":null,"tle2":null},{,"id":23560,"name":"ERS2","tle0":"ERS-2","tle1":"1 23560U 95021A   10320.16163206  .00000093  00000-0  50826-4 0  7517","tle2":"2 23560  98.5539  32.9598 0001338  91.0148 269.1209 14.32246397814217"},{,"id":23710,"name":"RSAT1","tle0":"RADARSAT-1","tle1":"1 23710U 95059A   10320.17983791  .00000119  00000-0  63183-4 0  8807","tle2":"2 23710  98.5810 324.6746 0001101  92.8062  40.0723 14.29987468784696"},{,"id":25260,"name":"SPOT4","tle0":"SPOT 4","tle1":"1 25260U 98017A   10320.17010216  .00000053  00000-0  45000-4 0  7757","tle2":"2 25260  98.6410  27.5855 0001153 118.8023 241.3191 14.20071681655704"},{,"id":25682,"name":"LSAT7","tle0":"LANDSAT 7","tle1":"1 25682U 99020A   10320.17475749  .00000092  00000-0  30424-4 0  4435","tle2":"2 25682  98.2322  26.4024 0001343 107.7462 252.3889 14.57097903616361"},{,"id":25994,"name":"TERRA1","tle0":"TERRA","tle1":"1 25994U 99068A   10320.19170658  .00000163  00000-0  46333-4 0  3452","tle2":"2 25994  98.2175  32.5202 0000685  91.9171 268.2128 14.57106702580447"},{,"id":27386,"name":"ENVISAT1","tle0":"ENVISAT","tle1":"1 27386U 02009A   10320.19615002  .00000074  00000-0  39337-4 0  6231","tle2":"2 27386  98.5352  25.2483 0001101 100.3084 259.8244 14.37466989455514"},{,"id":27421,"name":"SPOT5","tle0":"SPOT 5","tle1":"1 27421U 02021A   10320.21390906  .00000169  00000-0  10000-3 0  6893","tle2":"2 27421  98.7199  32.2015 0000869  81.7846 312.1186 14.20026544442540"},{,"id":27424,"name":"AQUA","tle0":"AQUA","tle1":"1 27424U 02022A   10319.45619378  .00000236  00000-0  62354-4 0  7940","tle2":"2 27424  98.2036 258.3378 0001264  54.1617 305.9677 14.57123781453943"},{,"id":27838,"name":"ORBVIEW3","tle0":"ORBVIEW 3","tle1":"1 27838U 03030A   10320.08123152  .00007152  00000-0  15929-3 0   425","tle2":"2 27838  96.9884   4.7112 0001609  66.1702  17.5471 15.43897611415052"},{,"id":28931,"name":"ALOS","tle0":"ALOS (DAICHI)","tle1":"1 28931U 06002A   10320.18010103  .00000316  00000-0  76098-4 0  3809","tle2":"2 28931  98.1413  32.2177 0001202  97.6884 262.4473 14.59582841256312"},{,"id":31598,"name":"SKYMED1","tle0":"COSMO-SKYMED 1","tle1":"1 31598U 07023A   10320.12036850 -.00000107  00000-0 -69111-5 0  8384","tle2":"2 31598  97.8612 144.9959 0001295  87.0739 273.0585 14.82168749186198"},{,"id":31698,"name":"TERRASAR-X","tle0":"TERRASAR-X","tle1":"1 31698U 07026A   10320.19654172  .00000567  00000-0  30202-4 0  8531","tle2":"2 31698  97.4447 325.2318 0001498  88.2507 336.5083 15.19155156189768"},{,"id":32376,"name":"SKYMED2","tle0":"COSMO-SKYMED 2","tle1":"1 32376U 07059A   10320.15411372  .00000305  00000-0  44808-4 0  2496","tle2":"2 32376  97.8610 145.0314 0001326  85.1830 274.9536 14.82171023158941"},{,"id":32382,"name":"RSAT2","tle0":"RADARSAT-2","tle1":"1 32382U 07061A   10320.20386927  .00000081  00000-0  48479-4 0  2364","tle2":"2 32382  98.5800 325.5126 0000996  92.7948 331.9613 14.29983070152587"},{,"id":33412,"name":"SKYMED3","tle0":"COSMO-SKYMED 3","tle1":"1 33412U 08054A   10320.14144199 -.00000060  00000-0 -10504-5 0  2737","tle2":"2 33412  97.8612 145.0178 0001265  88.0900 272.0466 14.82171643111404"},{,"id":36605,"name":"TANDEM-X","tle0":null,"tle1":null,"tle2":null}]}
```

Response from Production:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSatellite xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cstars.miami.edu/SAR">
  <Satellite>
    <id>10967</id>
    <name>SEASAT1</name>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>16613</id>
    <name>SPOT1</name>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>20436</id>
    <name>SPOT2</name>
    <tle0>SPOT 2</tle0>
    <tle1>1 20436U 90005A   10320.17586019  .00000436  00000-0  83185-4 0  7240</tle1>
    <tle2>2 20436  98.6342  56.4544 0155718 145.6368 215.5023 14.62070104 81087</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>21574</id>
    <name>ERS1</name>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>21867</id>
    <name>JERS1</name>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>23560</id>
    <name>ERS2</name>
    <tle0>ERS-2</tle0>
    <tle1>1 23560U 95021A   10320.16163206  .00000093  00000-0  50826-4 0  7517</tle1>
    <tle2>2 23560  98.5539  32.9598 0001338  91.0148 269.1209 14.32246397814217</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>23710</id>
    <name>RSAT1</name>
    <tle0>RADARSAT-1</tle0>
    <tle1>1 23710U 95059A   10320.17983791  .00000119  00000-0  63183-4 0  8807</tle1>
    <tle2>2 23710  98.5810 324.6746 0001101  92.8062  40.0723 14.29987468784696</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>25260</id>
    <name>SPOT4</name>
    <tle0>SPOT 4</tle0>
    <tle1>1 25260U 98017A   10320.17010216  .00000053  00000-0  45000-4 0  7757</tle1>
    <tle2>2 25260  98.6410  27.5855 0001153 118.8023 241.3191 14.20071681655704</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>25682</id>
    <name>LSAT7</name>
    <tle0>LANDSAT 7</tle0>
    <tle1>1 25682U 99020A   10320.17475749  .00000092  00000-0  30424-4 0  4435</tle1>
    <tle2>2 25682  98.2322  26.4024 0001343 107.7462 252.3889 14.57097903616361</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>25994</id>
    <name>TERRA1</name>
    <tle0>TERRA</tle0>
    <tle1>1 25994U 99068A   10320.19170658  .00000163  00000-0  46333-4 0  3452</tle1>
    <tle2>2 25994  98.2175  32.5202 0000685  91.9171 268.2128 14.57106702580447</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>27386</id>
    <name>ENVISAT1</name>
    <tle0>ENVISAT</tle0>
    <tle1>1 27386U 02009A   10320.19615002  .00000074  00000-0  39337-4 0  6231</tle1>
    <tle2>2 27386  98.5352  25.2483 0001101 100.3084 259.8244 14.37466989455514</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>27421</id>
    <name>SPOT5</name>
    <tle0>SPOT 5</tle0>
    <tle1>1 27421U 02021A   10320.21390906  .00000169  00000-0  10000-3 0  6893</tle1>
    <tle2>2 27421  98.7199  32.2015 0000869  81.7846 312.1186 14.20026544442540</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>27424</id>
    <name>AQUA</name>
    <tle0>AQUA</tle0>
    <tle1>1 27424U 02022A   10319.45619378  .00000236  00000-0  62354-4 0  7940</tle1>
    <tle2>2 27424  98.2036 258.3378 0001264  54.1617 305.9677 14.57123781453943</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>27838</id>
    <name>ORBVIEW3</name>
    <tle0>ORBVIEW 3</tle0>
    <tle1>1 27838U 03030A   10320.08123152  .00007152  00000-0  15929-3 0   425</tle1>
    <tle2>2 27838  96.9884   4.7112 0001609  66.1702  17.5471 15.43897611415052</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>28931</id>
    <name>ALOS</name>
    <tle0>ALOS (DAICHI)</tle0>
    <tle1>1 28931U 06002A   10320.18010103  .00000316  00000-0  76098-4 0  3809</tle1>
    <tle2>2 28931  98.1413  32.2177 0001202  97.6884 262.4473 14.59582841256312</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>31598</id>
    <name>SKYMED1</name>
    <tle0>COSMO-SKYMED 1</tle0>
    <tle1>1 31598U 07023A   10320.12036850 -.00000107  00000-0 -69111-5 0  8384</tle1>
    <tle2>2 31598  97.8612 144.9959 0001295  87.0739 273.0585 14.82168749186198</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>31698</id>
    <name>TERRASAR-X</name>
    <tle0>TERRASAR-X</tle0>
    <tle1>1 31698U 07026A   10320.19654172  .00000567  00000-0  30202-4 0  8531</tle1>
    <tle2>2 31698  97.4447 325.2318 0001498  88.2507 336.5083 15.19155156189768</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>32376</id>
    <name>SKYMED2</name>
    <tle0>COSMO-SKYMED 2</tle0>
    <tle1>1 32376U 07059A   10320.15411372  .00000305  00000-0  44808-4 0  2496</tle1>
    <tle2>2 32376  97.8610 145.0314 0001326  85.1830 274.9536 14.82171023158941</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>32382</id>
    <name>RSAT2</name>
    <tle0>RADARSAT-2</tle0>
    <tle1>1 32382U 07061A   10320.20386927  .00000081  00000-0  48479-4 0  2364</tle1>
    <tle2>2 32382  98.5800 325.5126 0000996  92.7948 331.9613 14.29983070152587</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>33412</id>
    <name>SKYMED3</name>
    <tle0>COSMO-SKYMED 3</tle0>
    <tle1>1 33412U 08054A   10320.14144199 -.00000060  00000-0 -10504-5 0  2737</tle1>
    <tle2>2 33412  97.8612 145.0178 0001265  88.0900 272.0466 14.82171643111404</tle2>
  </Satellite>
  <Satellite>
    <id>36605</id>
    <name>TANDEM-X</name>
  </Satellite>
</ArrayOfSatellite>
```

Even if i use the JavaScriptSerializer and return a string like below i get json wrapped in an xml tag with a `<string`> wrapping around the JSON data.

```
 var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 string resultJs = s.Serialize(result);
 return resultJs;
```

what gives? Is it IIS 7?
**EDIT:**
My web.config in both environments has:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Server 2008 **R2** and **IIS 7.5** did the trick for me.

I can now remove the handlers and it won't make a difference because it's .net 4.0.

The application now outputs JSON as expected. The only thing i did was the upgrade. I did nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

So production environment application uses XML instead of JSON. I would

1. Check if both environments have the same .NET framework versions.
2. Check if Web.config file on production environment has a line with reference to *ScriptHandlerFactory* like:

   `<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"
   type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`

Comment: Yes to both your questions except my reference to script factory is a bit different... will post in edit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your production site is targeting the older 2.0 ScriptHandlerFactory.  Make sure the site is set to a 3.5 or 4.0 site in IIS and [double check these configuration steps](http://encosia.com/2010/03/08/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/).

Also, make sure that your web service is decorated with the [ScriptService] attribute, not just the method itself (the [ScriptMethod] attribute there isn't actually necessary).

Comment: Both environments are set up with an application pool that runs .NET v4.0 Accourding to the configuration steps i don't even need the script handlers. So i've tried with and without them and with different versions. I do have the [ScriptService] attribute set. I'm going to install 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try removing that httpHandlers section on the server.  You don't need it with .NET 4, and that redefinition without explicit version might be falling back to a pre ASP.NET AJAX version of the assembly.

Comment: yeah, i tried that to no avail. I spawned 7.5 in a virtual machine and it works fine. So i'm going to upgrade my 2008 server to R2 and see if that works. However, i have a feeling it has something to do with all the other applications i have on the server. Some stupid mime setting or handler is probably being inherited. We'll see.